# Can Boost Proto adapt structures to a getter setter type API

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-phoenix, boost-proto

This seems like a common problem.  I've got two massive sets of code that need to be glued together: one that uses simple structs to hold data, the other has APIs that only expose getter/setter methods.

Is it possible to use Boost.Proto to define a mapping that could then be used to auto-generate the code that invokes the getters/setters?  Conceptually, the piece that seems most difficult is the synthesis of the function names to call, as that would involve compile-time string concatenation.  Other challenges involve mapping enum types from one to the other and custom initialization or conversion code.

Having a drop-in-place Proto-based solution that solves this problem would be a huge benefit to a wide variety of people.

E.g., I have an API with types such as this:

```
// These classes use getters/setters.
class Wheel
{
    int number_of_lugnuts_;
public:
    void initialize_wheel(bool);
    void set_number_of_lugnuts(int);
    int get_number_of_lugnuts();
};

class Engine
{
public:
    enum Gas_type_t {
        Unleaded,
        Premium
    };
private:
    Gas_type_t gas_type_;
public:
    void initialize_engine(bool);
    void set_gas_type(Gas_type_t);
    Gas_type_t get_gas_type();
};
```

While I also have millions of lines of code with the same data in simple directly-accessed structs:

```
// This code has simple data structures.
struct Car
{
    // These POD members are used by a large body of existing code.
    int lugnut_count;
    enum FUEL_TYPES {
        NORMAL_FUEL,
        HI_OCTANE
    };
    FUEL_TYPES fuelType;
};
```

Now the old-fashioned way is to add a lot of converters:

```
// The manual way to accomplish this for only the Wheel API.
// This has to be repeated similarly for the Engine API.
void convert_to_wheel(Wheel& w)
{
    w.initialize_wheel(true); // how can initialization be handled?
    w.set_number_of_lugnuts(lugnut_count);
}

void convert_from_wheel(Wheel& w)
{
    lugnut_count = w.get_number_of_lugnuts();
}
```

But, in the style of Boost.Spirit, I would like to use Proto to create an EDSL allowing me to specify the mapping, and have the compiler generate the repetitive code for me.

I can define enough Proto terminals to get this constructor to compile:

```
Car()
{
    // So can we define an API mapping like this?
    // Would strings be the only way to accomplish this?
    // This appears structurally similar to how Spirit grammars are defined.
    // This is a very rough attempt because it's unclear if this is possible.
    define_api_mapping<Wheel>
        (initialization_code((_dest_ ->* &Wheel::initialize_wheel)(true)))
        (map_member(lugnut_count) = map_getset("number_of_lugnuts"))
    ;
    define_api_mapping<Engine>
        (initialization_code((_dest_ ->* &Engine::initialize_engine)(true)))
        (map_member(fuelType) = map_getset("gas_type"))
    ;
    define_enum_mapping<FUEL_TYPES>
        (enum_value(NORMAL_FUEL) = enum_value(Engine::Unleaded))
        (enum_value(HI_OCTANE) = enum_value(Engine::Premium))
    ;
}
```

Conversion could conceptually be a simple function call:

```
// Declare some objects.
Car c;
Engine e;
Wheel w1, w2;

// Set some values.
c.lugnut_count = 20;

// Convert the old fashioned way.
c.convert_to_wheel(w1);

// Convert the new way.
convert(c, w2);
```

It's an ugly start, but I'm now baffled by how to mangle the names to generate the calls to the getters and setters.

Is this possible?  What would the solution look like?

Comment: I'm not convinced the end result is any better than manual mapping (just generate the code if you have something to generate from). Also, I find the concept of "converting a Car to a Wheel" (whereby you loose all the other information implicitly) dubious. At the very least, It's badly named.

Comment: Maybe poorly named. But everyone has faced this situation: two APIs, similar, but perhaps at differing levels of abstraction. I'm faced with it now, in fact!  Writing a bunch of boilerplate code is just taxing, if not downright depressing. There has got to be an automated way.

Comment: There might be. But in the absence of language reflection I would not spend too much time trying to shoe horn it into TMP. Been there. Done that. Look at popular libraries like AutoMapper for naming inspiration and concepts by the way. Good luck!

Comment: I suspect the C++ compiler cannot synthesize method call names at compile-time, but the solution would still be of tremendous benefit even if we have to explicitly specify the getter/setter member functions.  The question then becomes, how to synthesize the methods needed to perform the actual conversion...

Comment: Google "preprocessor token pasting". Together with Boost.PP you should get somewhere. I'm not sure what it brings you over just scripting that in a scripting language